# JQuery .css("color", "wanted_color") not working, alerts correct color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is acting very strange and I don't quite have any idea why. I'm setting the font color of my div, but it's not working. After setting the color, I'm alerting it in which it alerts correctly. It's simply not displaying the color change at all.

```
$("div.page").each(function() {
    if (!isNaN(parseFloat(this.id)) && isFinite(this.id) && this.id != page) {
        $(this).mouseover(function() {
            $(this).css("color", "blue");
            alert($(this).css("color"));
        });
    }
});
```

Here's a link to my test-site: http://az-web.info/repository/

Hover the '2' (below '1' on the page picker) and you'll see that it does not change, but alerts correctly.

Comment: Please don't ever use `<font>`. It's even worse than `<span style="">`. Use external styles.

Comment: Removed the font tag, and added coloring within the div's style. (at my php echoing of the div.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to look at the structure of **your** HTML. The divs that are being hovered contain `<font>` elements, which have a `color` attribute that overrides any inherited `color` styles. You need to change that value, like:

```
$("div.page").each(function() {
    if (!isNaN(parseFloat(this.id)) && isFinite(this.id) && this.id != page) {
        $(this).mouseover(function() {
            $(this).find("font").attr("color", "blue");
            //alert($(this).css("color"));
        });
    }
});
```

I'd think you also want a `mouseout` event to remove the style when you leave hovering it. Because of this insight, it's probably a better idea to uses classes for something like this, so you can add/remove the class, which is easier to maintain. Now thinking about that, it might be easier to use CSS completely for something like this, with the `:hover` pseudo class selector. Whether that means you even need `<font>` is up to you to determine. If you have a reason for doing everything the way you are, then keep on keeping on. Otherwise, you might want to revise for better maintenance/structure.

Comment: @JanDvorak `<blink><font>Burn</font></blink>`

Comment: @Ian you forgot the `big` tag and unclosed tags: `<blink><font color="red"><big><big>BURN</blink>`

Comment: Also, I know about the mouseout. I was just testing out why it wasn't working with the mouseover to begin with; gotta love debugging.

Comment: @OW2 you shouldn't have even _touched_ `mouseover` just to recolor elements.

Comment: @JanDvorak I don't see why you wouldn't use a `tr` as well, it's clearly better for formatting. Who closes tags nowadays anyways, and matching and in the right order? `<blink><font color="grurple"><tr><big><big>BURN</script type="wtf"></blink>`

Comment: @Ian Closing tags with attributes? You're giving me shivers.

Comment: @JanDvorak Haha! I hope you'd catch that. Only with the best attribute/values though

Comment: @Ian customer: Why dis not works?: `<font>red</font color="blue">` :-)

Comment: @JanDvorak You fool! Wrap it in `marquee`...`<marquee><font>red</font color="blue" \marquee>`

Comment: `<talbe border="back"<td<tr\><tr><link addr=google.com/my website>>>>>`; If unsure, add more closing tags.

Comment: @JanDvorak Oh man, haha! What's unfortunate is that IE probably LOVES this and renders it perfectly as you'd want, somehow.

Comment: @Ian what about now? It will definitely _hate_ the backslash.

Comment: @Ian Let's develop a new markup language. We already have some good ideas and the <big><big>world<//> _needs_ more markup languages. Note how you can close not one, but two tags with only four characters?

Comment: Also note how "a"b"c" is ambiguous, but “a“b”c” is perfectly clear? Let's use smart quotes. Everyone has UTF-8, right? :-)

Comment: @JanDvorak But what happens if you close more tags than you opened? Do you get 20 points? And why not require UTF-16? It's much better.

Comment: @Ian You're right about the UTF-8 issue. We should use a fixed-length encoding, like UTF-32 or UTF-64. UTF-64 is basically UTF-32 with extra padding but it's much faster than UTF-32 on x64 CPUs... or maybe UTF-20. It's slower to decode but also much more compact.

Comment: @JanDvorak I think the important thing to consider is how to incorporate Javascript's concept of `eval` into our new `HTML95` (in honor of Windows 95).